# Constraint on a boolean variable?

Tags: python, optimization, boolean, cvxpy

I am trying to implement a unit commitment problem with cvxpy with a rampup cost. However I am struggling to identify the ramp-ups. (when variable switch from 0 to any positive value)
In other terms, I have a variable g, positive and I want to determine when g is 0, or when g>0. I know it's often easier with some tolerance, that's not really an issue for me.

Below is some code to put this in context :

```
import cvxpy as cp
n=50    

g=cp.Variable(n)
ispos=cp.Variable(n,boolean=True)
```

I would need a constraint that looks like this :

- ispos=0 when g>=0
- ispos=1 when g<0

I tried to work around something like below,  but I cannot get a syntax CVXPY is happy with.

```
constraints=[ispos == (g>=0)]
```

I get the following error

> Exception: Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint or chain
> constraints, e.g., 1 >= x >= 0.

Also tried with this :

```
constraints+=[ off[t]+(1 if g[t]<=0 else 0)== 1 for t in range (n)]
```

But I get the following error:

> Exception: Cannot evaluate the truth value of a constraint or chain
> constraints, e.g., 1 >= x >= 0.

Comment: Search for *indicator constraints* (or semi-continous variables: but those are usually only available within commercial solvers' APIs).

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
ipsos[t] = 0 ==> g[t] >= 0
ipsos[t] = 1 ==> g[t] <= -0.001
```

This can be modeled as:

```
g[t] >= L[t]*ipsos[t]
g[t] <= -0.001*ipsos[t]+U[t]*(1-ipsos[t])
g[t] ∈ [L[t],U[t]]
```

I assume here that the lowerbound `L[t]` is a negative number. In practice, I would drop this -0.001 thing and just do:

```
g[t] >= L[t]*ipsos[t]
g[t] <= U[t]*(1-ipsos[t])
g[t] ∈ [L[t],U[t]]
```